# Как добавить class в сontact form7?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form7

Есть код который вывод уже cf7 в браузере

```
 <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap mkdf-s">
<select name="mkdf-s" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select mkdf-select" aria-invalid="false"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option>
></select></span>
```

и я бы хотел вставить свой класс

```
 <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap mkdf-s my-class">
```

кто то делал такое,  в документации инфы нету.

Answer (score 2):

В форме в поле select добавьте `class:my-class`:

```
[select mkdf "1" "2" class:my-class]
```

Документация с этой инфой [здесь](https://contactform7.com/checkboxes-radio-buttons-and-menus/), раздел `Drop-down menus`.